# keeping track of previous elements in foreach loop

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, foreach

Lets say I have a list of asteroid objects like so:

- 9_Amphitrite
- 24_Themis
- 259_Aletheia
- 31_Euphrosyne
- 511_Davida
- 87_Sylvia
- 9_Metis
- 41_Daphne

Each asteroid has a **title**, a **StartRoationPeriod**, and a **EndRoationPeriod**.

I need to concatenate their names based on how close the current asteroid StartRoationPeriod and previous asteroid EndRoationPeriod are to an orbital constant and then spit out the concatenated title.

So with the above list, the final objects may look like this:

- 9_Amphitrite
- 24_Themis;259_Aletheia
- 31_Euphrosyne;511_Davida;87_Sylvia
- 9_Metis
- 41_Daphne

This requires me to keep track of both the current and previous asteroids.

I started to write the loop, but I'm unsure of where or even how to check the current asteroids start rotation period against the previous asteroids end rotation period...basically, it just gets messy fast...

```
        string asteroid_title = string.Empty;
        Asteroid prev_asteroid = null;

        foreach (var asteroid in SolarSystem)
        {
            if (prev_asteroid != null)
            {
                 if (asteroid.StartRoationPeriod + OrbitalConstant >= prev_asteroid.EndRoationPeriod)
                 {
                      asteroid_title = asteroid_title + asteroid.Title;

                 } else {
                      asteroid_title = asteroid.Title;
                      yield return CreateTitle();
                 }
            }
            prev_evt = evt;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for you (If aggregate looks too complex try to convert it to a foreach,it's easy)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Program
{
    class Asteroid
    {
        public int EndRoationPeriod { get; internal set; }
        public string Name { get; internal set; }
        public int StartRoationPeriod { get; internal set; }
    }

    class AsteroidGroup
    {
        public int EndRoationPeriod { get; internal set; }
        public string Names { get; internal set; }
    }
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int OrbitalConstant = 10;
            List<Asteroid> SolarSystem = new List<Asteroid>()
            {
                new Asteroid() {  Name= "9_Amphitrite" ,StartRoationPeriod=10  ,EndRoationPeriod=50},
                new Asteroid() {  Name= "24_Themis" ,StartRoationPeriod=45,EndRoationPeriod=100},
                new Asteroid() {  Name= "259_Aletheia",StartRoationPeriod=40 ,EndRoationPeriod=150},
                new Asteroid() {  Name= "31_Euphrosyne" ,StartRoationPeriod=60,EndRoationPeriod=200},
                new Asteroid() {  Name= "511_Davida" ,StartRoationPeriod=195,EndRoationPeriod=250},
                new Asteroid() {  Name= "87_Sylvia" ,StartRoationPeriod=90,EndRoationPeriod=300},
                new Asteroid() {  Name= "9_Metis" ,StartRoationPeriod=100,EndRoationPeriod=350},
                new Asteroid() {  Name= "41_Daphne" ,StartRoationPeriod=110,EndRoationPeriod=400},
            };

             var result = //I skip the first element because I initialize a new list with that element in the next step
                          SolarSystem.Skip(1)
                          //The first argument of Aggregate is a new List with your first element
                          .Aggregate(new List<AsteroidGroup>() { new AsteroidGroup { Names = SolarSystem[0].Name, EndRoationPeriod = SolarSystem[0].EndRoationPeriod } },
                          //foreach item in your list this method is called,l=your list and a=the current element     
                          //the method must return a list                                         
                          (l, a) =>
                           {
                             //Now this is your algorithm
                             //Should be easy to undrestand

                              var last = l.LastOrDefault();
                              if (a.StartRoationPeriod + OrbitalConstant >= last.EndRoationPeriod)
                              {
                                  last.Names += " " + a.Name;
                                  last.EndRoationPeriod = a.EndRoationPeriod;
                               }
                               else
                                    l.Add(new AsteroidGroup { Names = a.Name, EndRoationPeriod = a.EndRoationPeriod });

                                //Return the updated list so it can be used in the next iteration
                                return l;
                           });
```

**A more compact solution**

```
var result = SolarSystem
             .Skip(1)
             .Aggregate( SolarSystem.Take(1).ToList(),
                         (l, a) => (a.StartRoationPeriod + OrbitalConstant >= l[l.Count - 1].EndRoationPeriod) ?
                         (l.Take(l.Count - 1)).Concat(new List<Asteroid> { new Asteroid() { Name = l[l.Count - 1].Name += " " + a.Name, EndRoationPeriod = a.EndRoationPeriod } }).ToList() :
                          l.Concat(new List<Asteroid> { a }).ToList()
                       );
```

Comment: wow, that's a lot of code. What do the lines .Skip(1) and .Take do and what does the line (l, a) => do?  thanks!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Added a few comments,Ignore the compact code,it was just for fun

Comment: thanks for the comments.  What is the variable, result?  Is it just a string?  thanks

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell In the first example it is a list of AsteroidGroup.In the "compact" version it is a list of Asteroid. as I said ignore the compact version